# Generate a new random point from a point based on some conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, random

Imagine I have a point $O$ whose positions are known. I have another point $A$ which has a known position and a known heading. I want to generate a new point $B$ from $A$ where the distance between two points is $5$ and the heading is chosen randomly in a range of (heading of point $A$ - $0.4$, heading of point $A$ + $0.4$) and the position is calculated from the distance and the new random chosen heading. Now here are my questions:

1- How to make sure that this random heading is chosen in a way that we are getting farther and farther from $O$? Meaning that if there is another point $C$ which is generated from $B$, this point $C$ needs to get farther and farther from $O$.

2- The same as the first question but this time we are getting closer and closer to $O$.

I am not looking for a solution where we generate a point and we check to see if the distance is increasing (or decreasing for 2) and if not we regenerate. I am looking for a solution that does this by calculation.

Thank you

Comment: What are the units on 0.4?

Comment: The expression 'getting farther and farther' is tricky. If you mean that you want the new point to be in the general direction of $OA$ then it suffices to set heading of the new point equal to the direction of $OA$ +/- $\frac{\pi}{2}$. On the other hand, if you want $|OB| > |OA| + |AB|$ then the problem becomes complicated. Note in this case that infinitely many points in the opposite direction of $OA$ (and far enough from $O$) satisfy the above condition too.

Comment: @Saeed As I said, I want to be in the same direction but it needs to be chosen randomly in the range of previous heading +- 0.4 radians. So should it still be +/$\pi / 2$?

Comment: @mrjamaisvu by heading of $A$ do you mean the angle of direction of $OA$?

Answer (score 0):

Your vector $\vec{A}$ is a distance $|\vec{A}| = A$ from $O$.

There will be a heading change $\theta$ such that $|\vec{A} + \vec{B}| = A$.

In other words, you have a circle of radius $A$ centered at the origin. Change the heading of $\vec{A}$ by $\theta$ to get the heading of $\vec{B}$. The value of $\theta$ is chosen such that the vector sum of $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ lands on the original circle. This means that you're at the same distance from $O$ that you were before.

You can calculate $\theta$ and then assign the full range of your random variable ($\pm 1$ say) to $\pm \theta$. This will ensure you never get closer to $O$.

To ensure you never get farther from $O$, it's the same argument, but use the range $\pi - \theta$ to $\pi + \theta$ instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did not catch what you mean by second line of your answer. Could you kindly explain more ?

Comment: Added explanation in the answer

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand. Firstly, as I said, the heading of point B is calculated from the heading of A such that it is a random value chosen from heading of A $\pm 0.4$ radians. Secondly, you say that the distance of vector A from O is A, what is the use of this ?

Comment: If you limit the angle between $\pm 0.4$ radians then you'll always be moving away from the origin. No need to check anything.

Comment: I was trying to give you a way to calculate the maximum heading change so that you weren't going closer to the origin. But that answer will be larger than $\pi/2$ which is more than $1.5$ radians.